# Is this an incorrect package name for my application

Tags: android, package-name

I own the domain name `freebee-tv.com` and I have recently published my app on `Google Play`. As I had some confusion with the hyphenation in my domain name, I simply published my app under the package name `com.freebeetv.android.aff47111Wc`. Could this create a problem as someone now, or sometime in the future may want to use the domain name `freebeetv.com`. Hopefully, someone can put my mind at rest with this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Purchase freebeetv from the owner.

Comment: I simply can't afford to purchase this domain name.

Comment: You can make anything as your package name, the domain name recommendation is only there so you won't collide with some else's package name. So just because you register a package with the name www.whitehouse.gov doesn't mean that you now own the domain name, and vise versa.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's ok becouse into the future you will have your gplay app like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.freebeetv.android.aff47111Wc probably will be great if you can make W into w... but is correct.... Also see this [reference](http://www.quora.com/Android-OS/Why-do-a-majority-of-Android-package-names-begin-with-com)